# mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean

Tags: php, mysqli

this was working about 5 minutes ago and has suddently stopped. It is a simple login form, please see code below

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true){
    header("location: welcome.php");
    exit;
}

// Include config file
require_once "db/config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;                            

                            // Redirect user to welcome page
                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p>Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
            <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.php">Sign up now</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

The error I get is `Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magic/client/login.php on line 83`

This was working about 5 minutes ago and has suddenly stopped and not sure why. Any ideas?

When it worked, it simply redirected the user to welcome.php and now it is not, and gives me that error. The code was taken of https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at what you're asking:

```
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
    // [...]
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

You always try to close your statement, even if it wasn't successfully created. You need to move that close attempt:

```
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
    // [...]

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Additionally, the fact that you got this error in the first place means your SQL query failed to be prepared, so there's some kind of error in there. You are currently not checking for that, which can make life difficult for you if you want to figure out *why* your code isn't working. I recommend adding a check for that:

```
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
    // [...]

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
} else {
    echo "Something's wrong with the query: " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Note that in production code, you don't want to output the `mysqli_error()` directly since it may reveal information about your database that isn't anybody's business but yours, so only do this while you're debugging.