# Page is just being refreshed when i try to add data. mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a trouble when i try to add a data to MySQL  database. I click the submit button and nothing happens just the page is being refreshed.

The following error occurs:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\loginsystm\register.php on line 92

Here's my PHP code:

```
    if(empty($name) && empty($password) && empty($confirm_password) && empty($thirdName) && empty($phone) && empty($email)){

    // Prepare an insert statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, thirdName, email, phone, age, password) VALUES ('$name', '$password', '$thirdName','$email','$phone')";
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,$sql)){
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $name, $password, $thirdName,$email,$phone);

        // Set parameters
        $param_name = $name;
        $param_thirdName = $thirdName;
        $param_email = $email;
        $param_phone = $phone;
        $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash

        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
            // Redirect to login page
            header("location: login.php");
        } else{
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
    }

    // Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

And here is my HTML

```
       <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $name_err; ?></span>
        </div>    
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Third Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="thirdName" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Phone number</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Confirm Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
            <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
        </div>
        <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.php">Login here</a>.</p>
    </form>
```

I know my html looks so bad but i don't have the time to manage it i'm sorry.
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mysqli\_stmt\_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli\_stmt, boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53459523/mysqli-stmt-close-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-stmt-boolean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very first line of your code:

```
if(empty($name) && empty($password) && empty($confirm_password) && empty($thirdName) && empty($phone) && empty($email)){
```

That condition is true if ALL parameters are empty. Since you're submitting the form, at least one of them is not empty, so the condition is false.

---

Also, you're not using prepared statements correctly:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, thirdName, email, phone, age, password) VALUES ('$name', '$password', '$thirdName','$email','$phone')";
```

Variables are encapsulated inside the SQL query, which is a security vulnerability named **SQL injection**.

You should also call `exit()` after your call to the `header` function.

Comment: Ok man now it's working. Thank you so much